# how to bind html in angular v1.2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was trying to make a blog in angularJS and on the post message section I want to get the message from json and add it to a content div like this

```
<div class="content">
    {{json.message}}
</div>
```

Now my div has a paragraph in it, it's practically a html code like this

```
<p>this is my message</p>
```

but when i do this, i see on the screen this

> `<p>this is my message</p>`

as text. I understand in previous versions i could use ng-bind-html-unsafe but i am using v1.2 of angularJS. Can anyone please show me code similar to ng-bind-html-unsafe so that I can make this work in v1.2? 
Thank you, Daniel!

Comment: Well I'll be damned bing has been used as a verb. Perhaps you meant bind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Strict Contextual Escaping services](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce) (`$sce`) in 1.2

Controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope,$sce) {
    $scope.myHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<span>Hello World!</span>');
}
```

Template:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="myHtml"></div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/GKnrE/1/

Comment: thank you very much, this works perefect! also thank you @Problematic

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to inject and use the [$sce](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce) service to mark it as trusted HTML, then use the [ng-bind-html](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtml) directive ([plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PrRo1v)):

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.name = $sce.trustAsHtml('<p>Hello World</p>');
});
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="content" ng-bind-html="name"></div>
</body>
```